# Can't edit Company Page on Stack Overflow Talent

Tags: support, edits, stack-overflow-talent

I've been added to our company team account on Stack Overflow Talent. I'd like to make some edits to our Company Page but the <kbd>Edit Company Page</kbd> button is disabled.

[image: SOmeta351338 first question example]

Related, if I go to the 'My Dashboard' page it shows our company page with a link to 'Edit Company Page'. Clicking this takes me to a Page Not Found page.

[image: SOmeta351338 second question example]

Is this a permission issue and if so, what permissions do a I need to be able to edit the page?